# Find all nodes with attribute that matches a pattern

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I have an xml

```xml
<mic_root state="mismatch">
  <RepoTrade state="mismatch">
    <TradeIds state="mismatch">
      <TradeId state="mismatch">
        <Id state="missing" />
        <Id1 state="added" />
        <Version state="mismatch">
          <mic_elemA_text>1</mic_elemA_text>
          <mic_elemB_text>2</mic_elemB_text>
        </Version>
      </TradeId>
      <TradeId state="mismatch">
        <Id state="mismatch">
          <mic_elemA_text>1</mic_elemA_text>
          <mic_elemB_text>2</mic_elemB_text>
        </Id>
      </TradeId>
    </TradeIds>
    <Fixings state="mismatch">
      <mic_elemA_text>
      </mic_elemA_text>
      <mic_elemB_text>123</mic_elemB_text>
    </Fixings>
    <SpecificDetail state="mismatch">
      <DirtyBondPrice mic_elemA_attr="%s=&quot;%s&quot;;%s=&quot;%s&quot;" mic_elemB_attr="%s=&quot;%s&quot;;%s=&quot;%s&quot;" state="mismatch" />
    </SpecificDetail>
  </RepoTrade>
</mic_root>
```

I need to find all those nodes which have an attribute like *mic_elem?_?????*. For example, in the xml above, I need to get *DirtyBondPrice*. I can find all those nodes which have a similar pattern with code like this:

```
Set xmlMatches = objResultsXML.GetRootElement.ChildElementsByPath("//*[starts-with(local-name(), 'mic_elem')]")
```

This gives me all nodes like `<Version><mic_elemA_text><mic_elemB_text>` & `<Id><mic_elemA_text><mic_elemB_text>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply the same approach for attribute as you did for nodes :

```
//*[@*[starts-with(local-name(), 'mic_elem')]]
```

Doesn't result in exact pattern: `mic_elem?_?????` but rather: `mic_elem?????`. That's maybe just enough since the latter pattern considered enough for finding nodes by name.

Comment: Thanks, that worked like a charm. Cannot believe that I didn't tried this combination. I need to learn more about xpath.